# React Native: save a value send to a Native Module on AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, react-native-native-module

I'm building a Native Module in Swift for a RN app where I "remove" the RN view and load a Storyboard, everything works fine but I need to send a value from RN to this Module but it is not being saved, I think it's because the controller is loaded again after a call it so the value is lost

This is a simplified version of my code, I call the `openMyModule` function on the RN side with the value and it should save the value on a variable, then it calls a function on AppDelegate that will open the Storyboard

```swift
@objc (MyModule) class MyModule : UIViewController {
  @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool { return true }
  
  var value = ""

  @objc func openMyModule(_ rn_value: String) -> Void {
    self.value = rn_value
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.goToNativeView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the function of AppDelegate

```objectivec
- (void) goToNativeView
{
  UIViewController *vc = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyModuleScreen" bundle:nil].instantiateInitialViewController;
  self.window.rootViewController = vc;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I think that when I call `goToNativeView` my controller is loaded again, that's why the value is lost

So, what I need is the value to still being available on my controller or save the value on AppDelegate and call it when I need it

There is any way I can achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else face this problem, here is how I solved:

I created another Swift file to save this value and made the variable static

```swift
class AnotherClass {
  static var value = ""
}
```

Then, when I just set the value when I receive it

```swift
@objc (MyModule) class MyModule : UIViewController {
  @objc static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool { return true }

  @objc func openMyModule(_ rn_value: String) -> Void {
    AnotherClass.value = rn_value
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.goToNativeView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and now it works!